# Linear fractional homogeneous differential equactions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, book-recommendation, fractional-calculus

What are some good graduate level texts for a mathematician to learn more about Linear fractional homogeneous and non. Homogeneous  differential equations?

Comment: It might help to know what you are using this for and what level of material you want. Are you a graduate student or undergrad? Are you doing this for strictly math or are you looking for physics/chemistry/engineering etc applications?

Comment: I am graduated and preparing for master of maths